# What are the difference between can.fixture and can.observe and where can they be used?

Tags: canjs

I am new canJs in general. I am having a hard time understanding the differences between can.fixture and can.observe and how they are both used?

To my understanding can.observe just listens for a function and keeps watching it, and it takes two parameters. As for fixture i am really lost because i keep on hearing about steal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are quite different:

## Observes

Observes are observable objects where you can receive an event whenever a value changes:

```
var ob = new can.Observe({
    name: 'Test'
});

ob.bind('change', function(ev, attr, how, newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('Something on ob changed, the new value is: ' + newVal);
});

ob.attr('name', 'Changed');
```

This can be useful in many places and makes view bindings possible (so when rendering a view with an Observe, your HTML will change whenever you update the Observe automatically). Read more on it [in the documentation](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Observe.html).

## Fixtures

Fixture just emulate AJAX responses and can help you to test your application or implement
functionality even if you REST backend isn't up and running yet:

```
// Static fixture
can.fixture("tasks", "fixtures/tasks.json");

can.ajax({
    url: 'tasks',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data) {
    // data is the content of fixtures/tasks.json
    // instead of making a request to tasks
});

// Dynamic fixture
can.fixture("/foobar.json", function(original, response){
    response(200, "success", { json: {foo: "bar" } }, {})
});
```

Where both come together is when using [Models](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.html). Models are basically just observes that get their data from a REST backend. [More on Models and fixtures](http://canjs.com/docs/can.fixture.store.html).

Comment: what is ob.bind that you have mentioned in can.observe?

Comment: All the information you need should be in the getting started guides and the documentation: http://canjs.com/docs/can.Observe.prototype.bind.html